# Changing size of text NSString in collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uicollectionviewcell

I have text in collection cell. **How can I change size of the text which is NSString?** I've tried something like

```
cell.author.text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

But it's not allowed, it says *Property 'font' not found on object of type 'NSString'*

```
CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.author.text = detailData.author;
```

Comment: `cell.author.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this:

```
cell.author.text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

should be, this:

```
cell.author.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since NSString doesn't have info about font (just the body=text), you have to specify the font in object that is displaying it - the author.

```
cell.author.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.author.text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

replace code with

```
cell.author.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
```